# How to disable basic http auth in grails 3.x?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, grails-3.0

I have started with grails 3 and working with spring boot starter security.
Here is my security config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
class CustomSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
    }

    @Bean
    CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        CustomAuthenticationProvider provider = new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // This is here to ensure that the static content (JavaScript, CSS, etc)
        // is accessible from the login page without authentication

        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/views/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        println "configuring security"
        http.httpBasic().disable()
        http.authorizeRequests().expressionHandler()
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();

    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Do you guys see any errors ? With this configuration whenever I open my root url, which should redirect to login page, keeps asking for popup authentication! Any ideas how can it be fixed ?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of these `@EnableWebSecurity`, `@EnableWebMvcSecurity`, and `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotations.

> However, it is important to only configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder in a class annotated with either @EnableWebSecurity, @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity, or @EnableGlobalAuthentication. Doing otherwise has unpredictable results.

References:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration

Comment: Hi MangEngkus, Thanks for your reply and suggestion I have implemented that , I found the problem and posting reply now.

Answer (score 0):

Got it,

The problem was my security config did not register automatically. I had to create bean in resources.groovy and that fixed it.

```
customSecurityConfig(CustomSecurityConfig)
```

I made the context scan my security config and that fixed it.
Cheers!